# How to find energy for bounded orbit?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, orbital-motion, potential-energy, hamiltonian-formalism

I have a time-independent Hamiltonian which describes a system. How do I find the energy threshold where the orbit stops being bounded? That is when there does not exists no zero-velocity surface?

Comment: Do you have a specific hamiltonian in mind?

Comment: Let's say we use the Hamiltonian: $\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2) + x^2y-\frac{y^3}{3} + \frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)^2$. How do I find the energy level when the motion becomes unbounded?